# How To make my bot send message when a specific user is typing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, events, discord, discord.py

I want to have my bot respond to when a specific user starts typing (i.e. me)

```
@client.event
   async def on_typing(channel, user, when):
       member = client.get_user(id='user_id')
       me = 'my_id'
         if me == member.typing:
             await channel.send('*cough* loser...')
```

If I use `==` to compare I get no response, if I use `!=` the bot responds to everyone as expected.

If I run the `if` statement as:

```
if me.typing:
    await channel.send('*cough* loser...')
```

The bot just responds to everyone again, what gives?

Comment: You should be comparing against `user.id`. `if user.id == your_id_as_integer : #do x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code as some errors:

- [`client.get_user()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get%20user#discord.Client.get_user) only takes one argument, which is a single `id` and has to be an integer. You'd have to use it this way → `user = client.get_user(id)`.
- Reading the doc, [`member.typing()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=typing#discord.Member.typing) that allows you to have this `xxxx is typing` and returns a context manager, not an integer, that's why your first `if` statement isn't triggered.
- As explained above, `me != member.typing` is always triggered because they will never be the same type and same value.

You don't really need to get a user object, you can just use `user.id` and compare it to the ID you want.
IDs must be integers, not strings or else, the `if` statement will never trigger.

```py
@client.event
async def on_typing(channel, user, when):
    if user.id == your_id: #Replace your_id with the id you want (must be an int)
        await channel.send('*cough* loser...')
```

**Reference:** discord.py documentation → [`discord.on_typing`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=typing#discord.on_typing)

Comment: Awesome thanks so much for laying it out, lol I'm pretty new to this and the api reference makes sense up to a point but still was above my level of understanding, thank you!